# Append or remove data from JSON

Tags: java, android, json

The result i want to get:

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"example1","description":"An example"},
{"id":2, "name":"example2","description":"Just another example"}, 
... ]
```

To add new data to JSON i tried this:

```
String jsonDataString = ALL MY JSON DATA HERE;
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonDataString);
JSONObject valuesObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
valuesObject.put("id", "3");
valuesObject.put("name", "example3");
valuesObject.put("description", "Yet another example");
list.put(valuesObject);
mainObject.accumulate("", list);
```

But i don't get a proper result.

And how to remove a JSON data depend on the value of the ID ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To build a fresh `JSONArray` you can use below codes:

   ```
   try {

       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

       // Object 1
       JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
       jsonObject1.put("id", 1);
       jsonObject1.put("name", "example1");
       jsonObject1.put("description", "An example");

       // Object 2
       JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
       jsonObject2.put("id", 2);
       jsonObject2.put("name", "example2");
       jsonObject2.put("description", "Just another example");

       // Add Object 1 & 2 JSONArray
       jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
       jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);


       Log.d("JSON", "JSON: " + jsonArray.toString());

   } catch (final JSONException e) {
       Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/JSON: JSON: [{"id":1,"name":"example1","description":"An example"},{"id":2,"name":"example2","description":"Just another example"}]
```

2. To add new `JSONObject` into existing `JSONArray` you can use below codes:

   ```
   // Your Existing JSONArray
   // [{"id":1,"name":"example1","description":"An example"},
   //  {"id":2, "name":"example2","description":"Just another example"}]

   String jsonDataString = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"example1\",\"description\":\"An example\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"example2\",\"description\":\"Just another example\"}]";

   try {

       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

       // Object 3
       JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject();
       jsonObject3.put("id", 3);
       jsonObject3.put("name", "example3");
       jsonObject3.put("description", "Third example");

       // Add Object 3 JSONArray
       jsonArray.put(jsonObject3);

       Log.d("JSON", "JSON: " + jsonArray.toString());

   } catch (final JSONException e) {
       Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/JSON: JSON: [{"id":1,"name":"example1","description":"An example"},{"id":2,"name":"example2","description":"Just another example"},{"id":3,"name":"example3","description":"Third example"}]
```

2. To remove `JSONObject` from `JSONArray` you can use below codes:

   ```
   // Your Existing JSONArray
   // [{"id":1,"name":"example1","description":"An example"},
   //  {"id":2,"name":"example2","description":"Just another example"},
   //  {"id":3,"name":"example3","description":"Third example"}]  

   String jsonDataString = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"example1\",\"description\":\"An example\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"example2\",\"description\":\"Just another example\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"example3\",\"description\":\"Third example\"}]";

   try {

       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

       Log.d("JSON", "JSON before Remove: " + jsonArray.toString());

       // Remove Object id = 2
       int removeId = 2;

       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
       {
           JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

           if (object.has("id") && !object.isNull("id")) {

               int id = object.getInt("id");

               if (id == removeId)
               {
                   jsonArray.remove(i);
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       Log.d("JSON", "JSON After Remove: " + jsonArray.toString());

   } catch (final JSONException e) {
       Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/JSON: JSON Before Remove: [{"id":1,"name":"example1","description":"An example"},{"id":2,"name":"example2","description":"Just another example"},{"id":3,"name":"example3","description":"Third example"}]

D/JSON: JSON After Remove: [{"id":1,"name":"example1","description":"An example"},{"id":3,"name":"example3","description":"Third example"}]
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Jis Maxi  If my answer helps you please upvote it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The root object of the json is an array so you should use a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`.

```
String jsonDataString = ALL MY JSON DATA HERE;
JSONArray mainObject = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);
JSONObject valuesObject = new JSONObject();
valuesObject.put("id", "3");
valuesObject.put("name", "example3");
valuesObject.put("description", "Yet another example");
mainObject.put(valuesObject);
```

Comment: Thank you, and what about removing one JSON data from it depending on the ID of each data in the array ?